# Android Room - Playlists and songs with position on cross reference table

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have playlists and songs. Each song has a position within a playlist. I want to query all playlists with their songs ordered by their respective position.

My code looks like this:

```
@Entity
data class Playlist(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    val name: String
)

@Entity
data class Song(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val length: Int
)

@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["playlistId", "songId"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Playlst::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["playlistId"]
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Song::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["songId"]
        )
    ]
)
data class PlaylistSongCrossRef(
    val playlistId: Long,
    val songId: Long,
    val position: Int
)

data class PlaylistWithSongs(
    @Embedded val playlist: Playlist,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "id",
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = PlaylistSongCrossRef::class,
            parentColumn = "playlistId",
            entityColumn = "songId"
        )
    )
    val songs: List<Song>
)
```

First I tried querying the playlists like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM playlist")
fun loadAllWithSongs(): Flow<List<PlaylistWithSongs>>
```

This works fine however the songs are not ordered per the cross reference position field.

Then I tried to construct the join myself like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Playlist " +
        "INNER JOIN PlaylistSongCrossRef ON PlaylistSongCrossRef.playlistId = Playlist.id " +
        "INNER JOIN Song ON Song.id = PlaylistSongCrossRef.songId " +
        "ORDER BY PlaylistSongCrossRef.position ASC"
)
fun loadAllWithSongsOrdered(): Flow<List<PlaylistWithSongs>>
```

The query works fine when executing it in the database inspector and also compiles without errors. However the result from Room only contains the playlist object. The songs list is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the songs are not ordered per the cross reference position field". Let's say there are 6 Songs and 3 Playlists. Are you trying to get all the songs but sorted like playlist after playlist? What do you get from the first query?

Comment: Hello, let me clarify this. A song can be part of multiple playlists. Each playlist has an order which is defined by the "position" field in the PlaylistSongCrossRef table. I want that the "songs" list of a PlaylistWithSongs object is sorted by that "position" field.

Answer (score 1):

> **What am I doing wrong?**

If you use `@Relation`, **then Room gets the children** (songs) **via a query that IT builds** that **gets ALL of the children for each parent (playlist) irrespective of the actual/full query**.

- As such, an ORDER BY clause ONLY considers the order if that changes the order of the parents.

  - The order of the children is as per the SQLite query optimizer (i.e. Room doesn't specify an order).
- attempts to better explain in more detail are included later
- **NOTE** furthermore, another complexity, explained later, lies with column naming ambiguity *(the reason for 0 Songs for a PlayList in your query)*, the ambiguity doesn't affect the suggested resolution in regards to ordering the songs according to poisition.

As such you need to override how Room acts. You can do this by having a function with a body that uses 2 queries.

1. The first to get the parent(s) (Playlist)
2. the second to get the children (songs) for the playlist ordered as required.

So for example:-

```
    /* Query 1 */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM playlist")
    fun getPlayLists(): List<Playlist>

    /* Query 2 */
    @Query("SELECT song.* FROM playlistsongcrossref JOIN song ON Song.id = playlistsongcrossref.songid WHERE playlistsongcrossref.playlistid = :playlistid ORDER BY playlistsongcrossref.position ASC")
    fun getOrderedSongsForAPlaylist(playlistid: Long): List<Song>

    @Transaction
    @Query("") /* Dummy so transaction is applied */
    fun getPlaylistsWithOrderedSongs(): List<PlaylistWithSongs> {
        /* Prepare the result value ()
        val rv = ArrayList<PlaylistWithSongs>()
        for(pl in getPlayLists()) {
            rv.add(PlaylistWithSongs(playlist = pl, songs = getOrderedSongsForAPlaylist(pl.id)))
        }
        return rv
    }
```

- You would need to wrap the Flow around the result (just the getPlaylistWithOrderedSongs function) as for convenience and brevity the example/demo runs on the Main thread.

**Example**

Consider the following that demonstrates (your code and then the suggested code):-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: DBStuff.TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: DBStuff.AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = DBStuff.TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        dao.insert(DBStuff.Song(1,"Song1",100))
        dao.insert(DBStuff.Song(2,"Song2",200))
        dao.insert(DBStuff.Song(3,"Song3",300))
        dao.insert(DBStuff.Song(4,"Song4",400))

        dao.insert(DBStuff.Playlist(1,"Playlist 1"))
        dao.insert(DBStuff.Playlist(2,"Playlist 1"))

        dao.insert(DBStuff.PlaylistSongCrossRef(1,3,1))
        dao.insert(DBStuff.PlaylistSongCrossRef(1,1,2))
        dao.insert(DBStuff.PlaylistSongCrossRef(1,4,4))
        dao.insert(DBStuff.PlaylistSongCrossRef(1,2,3))

        dao.insert(DBStuff.PlaylistSongCrossRef(2,4,1))
        dao.insert(DBStuff.PlaylistSongCrossRef(2,3,100))

        /* Not overriding how Room handles @Relation */
        for(pl in dao.loadAllWithSongsOrdered()) {
            logPLayListWithSongs(pl,"_1")
        }

        /* Overriding how Room handles @Relation */
        for (pl in dao.getPlaylistsWithOrderedSongs()) {
            logPLayListWithSongs(pl,"_2")
        }

    }

    fun logPLayListWithSongs(playlistWithSongs: DBStuff.PlaylistWithSongs, tagSuffix: String) {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for (s in playlistWithSongs.songs) {
            sb.append("\n\tSong is ${s.name}");
        }
        Log.d("DBINFO${tagSuffix}","PLaylist is ${playlistWithSongs.playlist.name} it has ${playlistWithSongs.songs.size} songs. They are :-$sb")
    }
}
```

- run on Main Thread for brevity/convenience

**Result**

After running the log contains:-

```
2022-12-15 07:43:35.015 D/DBINFO_1: PLaylist is Song3 it has 0 songs. They are :-
2022-12-15 07:43:35.015 D/DBINFO_1: PLaylist is Song4 it has 0 songs. They are :-
2022-12-15 07:43:35.015 D/DBINFO_1: PLaylist is Song1 it has 4 songs. They are :-
        Song is Song1
        Song is Song2
        Song is Song3
        Song is Song4
2022-12-15 07:43:35.015 D/DBINFO_1: PLaylist is Song2 it has 2 songs. They are :-
        Song is Song3
        Song is Song4
2022-12-15 07:43:35.015 D/DBINFO_1: PLaylist is Song4 it has 0 songs. They are :-
2022-12-15 07:43:35.015 D/DBINFO_1: PLaylist is Song3 it has 0 songs. They are :-


2022-12-15 07:43:35.018 D/DBINFO_2: PLaylist is Playlist 1 it has 4 songs. They are :-
        Song is Song3
        Song is Song1
        Song is Song2
        Song is Song4
2022-12-15 07:43:35.018 D/DBINFO_2: PLaylist is Playlist 1 it has 2 songs. They are :-
        Song is Song4
        Song is Song3
```

- Note the tag suffix (output has been amended to include spaces to separate the output from each method)
- The first is obviously not what is required

  - there are 2 underlying issues due to the query
  - the first is that the result of the query is the cartesian product and thus each row extracted is considered a playlist (complicated by 2)
  - the second is that the output includes ambiguous columns i.e. **id** and **name** for both playlist and song and hence how Playlist is the song name (Room select the last value of the ambiguous values)

    - A suggestion is that you make all column names unique. e.g. so rather than just **id** have **songId** and **playlistId** and also **songIdXref** and **playlistIdXref** (for the cross ref table)  and rather than **name** have **songName** and **playlistName**.
- The second is what you appear to be expecting.

> The query works fine when executing it in the database inspector and also compiles without errors.

**Is it? *(rhetorical)***. Using your query with the joins, with the data as per the above demo, then the output/result via App Inspection is:-

[image]

- as per the red **id** and **id:1** (the 1 added by app inspection) are the same and thus ambiguous. Likewise for **name** and **name1**. aka which id does Room select (rhetorical as the demo shows the last)

As can be seen, it is ordered according to the position column in the cross ref table.

**BUT** the result is the cartesian product i.e. an output row per combination of playlist song (aka a row per row in the cross ref table along with the respective playlist and song).

Room will for each row will create a PlaylistWithSong object for **EVERY** row. i.e. **6** PlaylistWithSong objects.

The first will be for the Playlist that has an **id** of 1.

Room will then retrieve ALL of the Songs as a List based upon the Playlist **id** which due to the Song also having a column called **id** which is **3**, becomes **3**. However, there are no rows in the cross ref table where the Playlist's **id** is 3 and hence there are no Songs in the list.

As the **name** column is ambiguous then the last name is used so PlayList 1 beceomes the name of the song i.e. **Song3**

Hence, using the example/demo data, the first PlayListWithSongs object becomes:-

```
PLaylist is Song3 it has 0 songs

- as per the demo output
```

etc (noting that when/if a Song id matches an existing Playlist id that Songs will be extracted)

**The Ambiguous column names**

From the above, it can be seen that the ambiguous column names (id and name) complicate matters. Perhaps consider the following that disambiguates the column names (for example):-

```
/* ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */
const val playlistIdColumnName = "playlistId"
const val playlistNameColumnName = "playlistName"
const val songIdColumnName = "songId"
const val songNameColumnName = "songName"
const val playlistIdXREFColumnName = "${playlistIdColumnName}Xref"
const val songIdXREFColumnName = "${songIdColumnName}Xref"

@Entity
data class Playlist(
    @ColumnInfo(name = playlistIdColumnName) /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = playlistNameColumnName) /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */
    val name: String
)

@Entity
data class Song(
    @ColumnInfo(name = songIdColumnName) /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = songNameColumnName) /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */
    val name: String,
    val length: Int
)

@Entity(
    primaryKeys = [playlistIdXREFColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */, songIdXREFColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Playlist::class,
            parentColumns = [playlistIdColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */],
            childColumns = [playlistIdXREFColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */]
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Song::class,
            parentColumns = [songIdColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */],
            childColumns = [songIdXREFColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */]
        )
    ]
)
data class PlaylistSongCrossRef(
    @ColumnInfo(name = playlistIdXREFColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */)
    val playlistId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(songIdXREFColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */)
    val songId: Long,
    val position: Int
)

data class PlaylistWithSongs(
    @Embedded val playlist: Playlist,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = playlistIdColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */,
        entityColumn = songIdColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */,
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = PlaylistSongCrossRef::class,
            parentColumn = playlistIdXREFColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */,
            entityColumn = songIdXREFColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */
        )
    )
    val songs: List<Song>
)

@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(playlist: Playlist): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(song: Song): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(playlistSongCrossRef: PlaylistSongCrossRef): Long

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM playlist")
    fun loadAllWithSongs(): List<PlaylistWithSongs>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Playlist " +
            "INNER JOIN PlaylistSongCrossRef ON PlaylistSongCrossRef.${playlistIdXREFColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */} = Playlist.${playlistIdColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */} " +
            "INNER JOIN Song ON Song.${songIdColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */} = PlaylistSongCrossRef.${songIdXREFColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */} " +
            "ORDER BY PlaylistSongCrossRef.position ASC"
    )
    fun loadAllWithSongsOrdered(): List<PlaylistWithSongs>


    @Query("SELECT * FROM playlist")
    fun getPlayLists(): List<Playlist>
    @Query("SELECT song.* FROM playlistsongcrossref JOIN song ON Song.${songIdColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */} = playlistsongcrossref.${songIdXREFColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */} WHERE playlistsongcrossref.${playlistIdXREFColumnName /*<<<<< ADDED to DISAMBIGUATE column names */} = :playlistid ORDER BY playlistsongcrossref.position ASC")
    fun getOrderedSongsForAPlaylist(playlistid: Long): List<Song>

    @Transaction
    @Query("") /* Dummy so transaction is applied */
    fun getPlaylistsWithOrderedSongs(): List<PlaylistWithSongs> {
        val rv = ArrayList<PlaylistWithSongs>()
        for(pl in getPlayLists()) {
            rv.add(PlaylistWithSongs(playlist = pl, songs = getOrderedSongsForAPlaylist(pl.id)))
        }
        return rv
    }
}

@Database(entities = [Song::class,Playlist::class,PlaylistSongCrossRef::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

Then the output (only interested in the first set, as the second set using the suggested query works as expected) in the log becomes:-

```
2022-12-15 13:39:19.438 D/DBINFO_1: PLaylist is Playlist 1 it has 4 songs. They are :-
        Song is Song1
        Song is Song2
        Song is Song3
        Song is Song4
2022-12-15 13:39:19.438 D/DBINFO_1: PLaylist is Playlist 1 it has 2 songs. They are :-
        Song is Song3
        Song is Song4
2022-12-15 13:39:19.438 D/DBINFO_1: PLaylist is Playlist 1 it has 4 songs. They are :-
        Song is Song1
        Song is Song2
        Song is Song3
        Song is Song4
2022-12-15 13:39:19.439 I/chatty: uid=10839(a.a.so74796591kotlinroomcrossref) identical 1 line
2022-12-15 13:39:19.439 D/DBINFO_1: PLaylist is Playlist 1 it has 4 songs. They are :-
        Song is Song1
        Song is Song2
        Song is Song3
        Song is Song4
2022-12-15 13:39:19.439 D/DBINFO_1: PLaylist is Playlist 1 it has 2 songs. They are :-
        Song is Song3
        Song is Song4
```

and because of the disambiguation the PlayList **id**s are the correct values and the first Playist (id = 1) always retrieves the 4 songs and the second (id=2) always retrieves the 2 Songs. **BUT** the Songs are not ordered according to the ORDER BY (as Room uses **it's** underlying/build query to retrieve the songs).

---

**Moving Forward *(one step beyond the question)***

---

Although the resolution (2 queries and function with body) above probably answers the question. You may then consider but the **position** is needed.

This adds a further complexity as neither the Song object nor the PlayList object caters for the **position**.

As such, if required, a **SongWithPlayListPosition** object (POJO) would be required. e.g.

```
data class SongWithPlayListPosition(
    @Embedded
    val song: Song,
    val position: Int
)
```

Then a PlaylistWithSongWithPlayListPositions object (POJO) would be required e.g.

```
data class PlaylistWithSongWithPlayListPositions(
    @Embedded val playlist: Playlist,
    val songs: List<SongWithPlayListPosition>
)
```

Then suitable `@Dao` annotated functions for extracting the above objects would be required, so:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM playlistsongcrossref JOIN song ON Song.${songIdColumnName} = playlistsongcrossref.${songIdXREFColumnName} WHERE playlistsongcrossref.${playlistIdXREFColumnName} = :playlistid ORDER BY playlistsongcrossref.position ASC ")
fun getOrderSongsWithPositionForAPlaylist(playlistid: Long): List<SongWithPlayListPosition>


@Transaction
@Query("")
fun getPlayListsWithOrderedSongsAlongWithPosition(): List<PlaylistWithSongWithPlayListPositions> {
    val rv = ArrayList<PlaylistWithSongWithPlayListPositions>()
    for(pl in getPlayLists()) {
        rv.add(PlaylistWithSongWithPlayListPositions(playlist = pl, songs = getOrderSongsWithPositionForAPlaylist(pl.id)))
    }
    return rv
}
```

And for the demo (activity code) then:-

```
fun logPlayListWithSongsAlongWithPosition(playlistWithSongWithPlayListPositions: PlaylistWithSongWithPlayListPositions, tagSuffix: String) {
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    for (s in playlistWithSongWithPlayListPositions.songs) {
        sb.append("\n\tSong is ${s.song.name} Length is ${s.song.length} Position in Playlist is ${s.position}")
    }
    Log.d("DBINFO${tagSuffix}","Playlist is ${playlistWithSongWithPlayListPositions.playlist.name} it has ${playlistWithSongWithPlayListPositions.songs.size} songs. They are :-$sb")
}
```

- the function to log a Playlist with it's ordered songs and the position in the playlist

and to use the new function :-

```
    /* Additional with position of song in playlist */
    for (pl in dao.getPlayListsWithOrderedSongsAlongWithPosition()) {
        logPlayListWithSongsAlongWithPosition(pl,"_3")
    }
```

The result of the new 3rd stage/method being:-

```
2022-12-15 14:35:41.762 D/DBINFO_3: Playlist is Playlist 1 it has 4 songs. They are :-
        Song is Song3 Length is 300 Position in Playlist is 1
        Song is Song1 Length is 100 Position in Playlist is 2
        Song is Song2 Length is 200 Position in Playlist is 3
        Song is Song4 Length is 400 Position in Playlist is 4
2022-12-15 14:35:41.762 D/DBINFO_3: Playlist is Playlist 1 it has 2 songs. They are :-
        Song is Song4 Length is 400 Position in Playlist is 1
        Song is Song3 Length is 300 Position in Playlist is 100
```

- an alternative approach would be to have a PlayListWithSongAlongWithTheXrefRow which would include the position and also the id's of the Playlist and the Song