# Unable to get correct values in Room by using @Relation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have three tables in my Room database, my query should return a list of products that contains details about them.

All products are inserted based on a `documentId` so when the query is done I need to get in the list **only** the items for that `documentId`.

The DAO looks like this:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM document_products dp LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = dp.productId LEFT JOIN products_barcodes ON products_barcodes.barcode = dp.productId WHERE dp.documentId = :documentId AND (products_barcodes.barcode = dp.productId OR products.id = dp.productId) ORDER BY timestamp ASC")
fun getProductsWithDetails(documentId: Long): Flow<List<DocumentProductWithDetails>>
```

And if I test the query in a table like this:

[image]

Where `documentId` is 5 the query returns the correct values:

[image]

But those values are incorrect in the application probably cause of @Relation in DocumentProductWithDetails but I'm unable to find the issue, in facts inside the application the data is shown as this:

[image]

So as the item with `productId` is saved three times it is showing the last item instead of the one related to `documentId`

The data class which contains `@Relation` annotation looks like this:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class DocumentProductWithDetails(
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "productId"
    )
    var product: DocumentProduct,
    @Embedded
    var details: ProductWithBarcodes?
)
```

Where DocumentProduct and ProductWithBarcodes:

```
data class DocumentProduct(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long,
    var productId: String,
    var quantity: Float,
    var orderQuantity: Float,
    var purchase: Float,
    var documentId: Long,
    var labelType: String?,
    var timestamp: Long?
)

data class ProductWithBarcodes(
    @Embedded
    var product: Product,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "productId"
    )
    var barcodes: List<Barcode>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So as the item with productId is saved three times it is showing the last item instead of the one related to documentId

**IF** any columns of the query have the same column name, the values assigned may(will be) inconsistent in that the value of the last column, of the repeated name, will be the value assigned to all the other columns that have the same name (etc).

I would suggest that **the fix** is to use **unique column names**. e.g. instead of **productId** in the Barcode that you use a column name more indicative of the use of the value, it could be considered as a map to the product so perhaps **barcode_productIdMap**.

- it is not the query that is at fault but how Room handles retrieving and assigning values.

Consider your second image (with some marking):-

[image]

The above is explained in more detail, with examples, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74796591/android-room-playlists-and-songs-with-position-on-cross-reference-table/74804069#74804069)

Which is the correct id, productId, quantity (*Rhetorical*).

How is Room supposed to know what goes where? (*Rhetorical*)

Consider that the following query extracts exactly the same data (but with the data columns in a different sequence):-

```
@Query("SELECT products.*,products_barcodes.*,document_products.* FROM document_products dp LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = ....
```

How is Room meant to cope with the different order (should the correct productId be the first or the second (*Rhetorical*)).

- with unique column names the column order is irrelevant as Room then knows exactly what column is associated with what field, there is no ambiguity.
- with unique columns tablename.columname can be reduced to just the column name in the SQL, so the SQL can be simplified.

Comment: Even by changing column names in uniques i'm still having the exactly same issue, I've exported a [CSV](https://pastebin.com/kpMNVUD4) from the QUERY result. Another point I've noticed is that for each `document_products_productIdMap` in any case indifferently from `documentId` value in the query only the last value is returned, but if I change the @Relation() to produce a list instead DocumentProduct I'd have there all products with that `document_products_productIdMap`

Comment: I was able to solve it with unique column names and by using @Embedded on both `product` and `details` properties in `DocumentProductWithDetails` instead of @Relation, could it be a valid solution?

Comment: @NiceToMytyuk Yes, @Embedded basically copies the fields from the embedded class so each output row would build an object according to the POJO. Whilst @Relation results in the @Related field being built by an underlying query that Room generates and that retrieves ALL children of the parent (if a `List<the_child>`).